# ways to find all aws public resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops

I able to find that in my research there are some of the ways to find all our aws resources but will you suggest any solution to find public resources in aws our account.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way that you can find all resources that are allowed to communicate with outside world. However, the only way for **most** of the resources in AWS can connect to the internet through a VPC that is configured to allow access to `0.0.0.0/0` network with Security Group and ACL. So what you can do is to search for VPC ID on resources categories and if any results you get can connect to the internet.

This can be a very tedious task and this is **NOT** 100% guaranteed to find all resources as some resources has self-sustained VPC per resource such as S3. So my suggestion is you get used to using **tags** for resources.

Also maybe think about using ***infrastructure as code*** approach using something like [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/intro/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you have all of your instances in a VPC you could enable VPC Flow Logs on your VPC and then monitor all VPC traffic that way.

For the instances that are not in VPC's you could have CloudWatch logs enabled for that instance and then monitor the traffic that way.

Your instances should have security groups attached to them so that you could monitor the rules, and see if you have an OutBound Set to 0.0.0.0/0

Answer (score 0):

You can give Netflix's [Security Monkey](https://github.com/Netflix/security_monkey) a try. The tool will make a complete report of all secure and insecure AWS assets including Security Groups, IAM Policies and S3 Buckets. In fact, it also provides a ticketing like system to collab on such problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IAM Access Analyzer console](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/07/quickly-identify-public-access-to-resources-using-iam-access-analyzer-console/)